# How to initalize a nested list in Golang?

Tags: go

I have a nested struct like this:

```
type Project struct {               
    FolderStructure     []FolderItem 
    Description         string
}

type FolderItem struct {
    SubFolderStructure  []SubFolderItem
    Description         string
}

type SubFolderItem struct {
    SubSubFolderStructure []SubSubFolderItem
    Description           string
}

type SubSubFolderItem struct {
    Content               string
    Description           string
}
```

I wonder how to initalize it, otherwise `invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` will be thrown out.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use make, for example, to initialize the slices.

Comment: First of all accessing `Project{}.FolderStructure` or any nested array won't panic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to initialize is to create multiple instances as variables & then reuse them to assign the values to the nested structures.

Here is the working example: https://go.dev/play/p/6p3VFljyqom and same below, this is just one way of doing it and feel it's the easiest.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Project struct {
    FolderStructure []FolderItem
    Description     string
}

type FolderItem struct {
    SubFolderStructure []SubFolderItem
    Description        string
}

type SubFolderItem struct {
    SubSubFolderStructure []SubSubFolderItem
    Description           string
}

type SubSubFolderItem struct {
    Content     string
    Description string
}

func main() {
    ssfi1 := SubSubFolderItem{
        "content1",
        "description1 - SubSubFolderItem",
    }
    ssfi2 := SubSubFolderItem{
        "content2",
        "description2 - SubSubFolderItem",
    }
    sfi := SubFolderItem{
        SubSubFolderStructure: []SubSubFolderItem{ssfi1, ssfi2},
        Description:           "description 1 - SubFolderItem",
    }
    fi := FolderItem{
        SubFolderStructure: []SubFolderItem{sfi, sfi},
        Description:        "description 1 - FolderItem",
    }
    p := Project{
        FolderStructure: []FolderItem{fi, fi},
        Description:     "description 1 - Project",
    }

    fmt.Println(ssfi1)
    fmt.Println(ssfi2)
    fmt.Println(sfi)
    fmt.Println(fi)
    fmt.Println(p)
}
```